# Expected Insert Rate in Neo4j

Tags: performance, neo4j

What would an average insert rate be for a Neo4j server running on something like an AWS m1.xlarge?  We're running into write bottlenecks in our instance but it appears memory, CPU, and disk are all not heavily loaded.

Is there some configuration to help make Neo4j run faster on machines where it has more headroom to run?

Cypher looks something like:

`START 
    to=node:node_auto_index('key:"string1" AND type:"type1"')
    from=node:node_auto_index('key:"string2" AND type:"type2"')
    CREATE UNIQUE from-[:TYPE1_TO_TYPE2 {count:1}]->to`

UPDATE: Inserts seem to be fine when I do batches of 100-300 sequentially but if they run in parallel I begin to see more problems with writes taking a long time.

Comment: If this is an initial insert, you could use the bulk inserter, which circumvents transactions. This may be your problem if you are using the HTTP interface. check this out http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html

Comment: I'm using py2neo and creating the relationships using cypher "create unique".  I'm adding the cypher queries in batch adding them using "append_cypher" and then executing the batch using run()

Comment: Can you post your cypher statement, or something like it?

Comment: What's the size of the batch ? Have you tried multiple ones ? Have you tried streaming ? We insert data in batches over the REST Api in an m1.large and we get ~600 operations (node / rel creation, properties updates) per second

Comment: Is ~600 operations/second a top end performance metric?  I updated the question with some more details.